# d3 Not "De-Selecting" Nodes Properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have this "select node" functionality in my d3 force-graph. For some reason it is not behaving as it should. The code should make it so when a user double clicks the node it gets selected/deselected (Goes back to normal color/turns yellow). Everything works when you are selecting then deselecting a node. The issue comes in the following cases:

1. If you select a node A then select node B (at this point they are both yellow as it should) then go back and double click node A to de-select it gets read as being selected again (stays yellow).
2. When you select node A then select node B. Then you double click node B to de-select it will work as intended. But when you go back to double click node A (which is still selected) to de-select it will get read in as selected.

Here are some code snippets from where I think the issue is.

```
var edges = [];
var nodes = [];
var nodesHash = {};

function update() {

    // clear stack of selected nodes
    selectedNodes = [];

    // Update link data based on edges array.
    link = link.data(edges);

    // Create new links
    link.enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", 1.5);

    // Delete removed links
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update node data based on nodes array.
    node = node.data(nodes);

    // Create new nodes
    node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d.data['id'] })
            .call(force.drag)
            .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
            .on('mouseleave', restore)
            .on('dblclick', highlight);

    // Delete removed nodes
    node.exit().remove();

    node.append("circle").attr("r", 11);
    node.classed("selected", function(d) { return d === d.selected; })

    // Node behavior for checking if selected otherwise colors nodes to color given from JSON.
    node.style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.selected === false) {
            return d.data['color']
            update();
        }
        else {
            return "yellow";
            update();
        }
    }).select("circle").style("stroke", "black");

    // Link color based on JSON data.
    link.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data['color'] });

    // Adds text to nodes
    node.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .text(function (d) { return d.data['label']; });

    // Creates an index used to figure out neighbor nodes.
    root.edges.forEach(function (d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.data.source + "," + d.data.target] = 1;
    });

    // responsive behavior for graph based on window.
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

    force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    });
    force.start();
}

// Reset Mouse Variables
function resetMouseVars() {
    mousedown_node = null;
    mouseup_node = null;
    mousedown_link = null;
}

// Highlighting of selected node.
function highlight(d) {
    mousedown_node = d;
    if (mousedown_node != selected_node) {
        console.log("Selected: " + mousedown_node.data['id']);
        selected_node = mousedown_node;
        selected_node.selected = true;
    }
    else {
        console.log("De-Selected: " + mousedown_node.data['id']);
        selected_node = mousedown_node;
        selected_node.selected = false;
    }
    resetMouseVars();
    update();
}

function spliceLinksForNode(node) {
    toSplice = edges.filter(
            function(e) {
                return (e.source === node) || (e.target === node); });
    toSplice.map(
            function(e) {
                edges.splice(edges.indexOf(e), 1); });
}

// Delete node with prompt
function deleteNode() {
    console.log("Prompted to delete: " + selected_node);
    if (confirm("Deleting selected elements will remove them from the graph entirely. Are you sure?")) {
        if (!selected_node) alert("No node selected");
        if (selected_node) {
            console.log("Deleted: " + selected_node);
            selected_node.removed = true;
            nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(selected_node), 1);
            spliceLinksForNode(selected_node);
        }
        selected_node = null;
        update();
    }
}
```

So in my code the `node.on('dblclick', highlight)` is just changing the currently selected nodes property of whether it is selected or not. The `node.style` is doing the actual checking of the property and changing the color.

Any assistance on why this odd behavior is happening will be appreciated!

Comment: could you give us a jsfiddle?

Comment: I haven't been able to get jsfiddle to run my code in the past. I am not sure why. I'll try to see if I can get it up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select A, then `selected_node` gets set to A.

Then, if you select B, then `selected_node` gets set to B

Then, if you click A again then, inside `highlight()`, the expression  `mousedown_node != selected_node` evaluates to `true` because A, which is `mousedown_node` is not equal `selected_node`, which is still B, from the previous selection.

So that's a bug.

If you are allowing multi-selection then there's no way a single variable `selected_node` is sufficient to capture the selection state. If you had a `selected_nodes` **Array** from which you add and remove nodes, then you can check if `selected_nodes.indexOf(mousedown_node) > -1` to determine if it's selected.

But really, I don't see why you need all this logic at all — unless maybe some code that you didn't include is relying on `selected_node`. Really, all your highlight function needs to be is just

```
function highlight(d) {
  d.selected = !d.selected;
  update();
}
```

And that should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I had `selected_node` as a variable is because I have another function that uses that variable to determine what node to delete. I can see how your highlight function will make it so multiple nodes can have `d.selected`. My question is... without the `selected_nodes` how can I have my function check what node to delete just based off the `d.selected`. I've updated my question with my delete function.

Comment: The simplest way that `delete_nodes()` can obtain an array of just selected nodes — which are a subset of all `nodes` — is by filtering the full list of nodes: `selectedNodes = nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.selected; })`. That would be my recommended way, since it keeps the `highlight` function as simple as I showed above. The only good reason not to do it this way is if `nodes` has tens of thousands of elements and so looping over them is prohibitive. For that (unlikely) case, see following comment....

Comment: You can make a global array `selected_nodes = []`. Then, where you're current highlight function sets `selected_node = mousedown_node` change it to `selected_nodes.push(mousedown_node`. To determine if a node is already selected, you check `selected_nodes.indexOf(someNode) > -1`. To remove a deselected node from that array: `selected_nodes.splice(selected_nodes.indexOf(selected_node), 1);`